# Flash JSFL Extension - How can I disable Authortime Sharing for a given library item?

Tags: flash, jsfl

How can I disable Authortime Sharing for a given library item?

I have tried the following:

```
if (libraryItem.sourceLibraryName) libraryItem.sourceLibraryName = "";
if (libraryItem.sourceFilePath) libraryItem.sourceFilePath = "";
```

But I get this error:

```
Error: Invalid value for property sourceLibraryName.
```

Related documentation here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flash/cs/extend/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9024f3f-7f76CS5.html

**Update:**
I can't seem to figure out how to disable Authortime Sharing through the IDE either. Knowing how to do that may lead to the JSFL equivalent.

Comment: JSFL has always been a bit odd. When I was using it I remember finding quite a lot of bugs, and that the implementation didn't always follow the documentation. My best idea is to try and play with `sourceAutoUpdate` and see if that works.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that seems to have no effect.

Comment: Which version of Flash are you using?

Comment: Flash CC 2014, however, I would like my JSFL script to work across at least a few recent versions.